# libvirt NON TLS connectivity

Tags: libvirt

virsh seems to require TLS even when tls is set to 0 in libvirtd.conf.  I would prefer not to use TLS since I am working in an secure environment and as such TLS only adds complication, but doesn't add anything to security (If you are in position to be able to exploit the plain text I have far bigger problems on my hands).

I have drawn blank, in terms of google to find a solution to this.  Every time I try to make a remote virsh connection it says that there are no certs installed (which is true).

Comment: If someone gets into your internal network, you want to limit the damage they can do. You don't want to be forced to say you have no idea what an attacker was able to access. In any case, you can also use it over ssh, with ssh keys.

Comment: Trust me in my case it simply would make no difference if you got far enough to be able to connect, the game would be over and I would have a far bigger problem on my hands :) 
encryption is a good thing, but ultimately it is only helpful in specific situations.  For instance if you have access to the public/private keys it only gives a hacker couple of seconds of annoyance and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'spicy' (which comes from 'yum install spice-gtk-tools' on fedora) to directly open spice display.

Sample:

```
$ virsh domdisplay 10 spice   <== figure out 'spice port' of target VM
spice://localhost:5906        <== well it is listen on  localhost:5906'

$ spicy -h localhost -p 5906  <== then use spicy to open spice display.
```

Good luck:)

Comment: That is only for the console, I am actually looking for management of libvirt itself.  So for instance I can do something like this virsh -c //someserver/server list.  
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "virsh -c qemu+ssh://root@${your_remote_server}/system list "  ?   This goes via 'ssh', irrelevant with 'tls' .

Comment: That's a great idea, I will try that!